# How to remove these whitespaces in robot framework?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, pycharm, robotframework

so, I perform a GET Request, and this is my response:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRVvT.png)

Also, this is part of my code performed in order to obtain that response. Good thing to mention is that the GET request is a custom keyword.

```
    ${Links}=    GET_Request     http://rhel8-nms28:8083    ${URL_GET_Links_List}     #GET_DEVICES endpoint
    ${Links_Response}=    decode bytes to string    ${Links}   UTF-8     #turn the response into a list
```

My problem is that there shouldn't be any whitespaces there. And I don't really know how to deal with that.
I tried using Replace String, also strip(), but without success.

If anyone has any idea it would be amazing.

The response should look like that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbQhS.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your response is not so much clear but I would try to answer it as much as I can. Hoping that your response is as it is showing in image.

```
${Links}=    GET_Request     http://rhel8-nms28:8083    ${URL_GET_Links_List}     
${string_response}    Convert JSON to String    ${Links.json()}
${string_response}    Replace String Using Regexp    ${string_response}    ":[\\s]{1,}   ":${SPACE}    # Here it will match spaces in your response and replace with single space padded with ":
${Links}     Convert String to JSON    ${string_response}
```

Try this, it might help.

Comment: You need to Import JSONLibrary & String along.